# How can I make DRY in filter.php of Laravel4.1

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel4.1.

I want to same process in different filters and same Object like the followings.

```
Route::filter('filter1', function(){
  $sameObject = // I want to fetch sameObject;
  View::share('obj', $sameObject);
});

Route::filter('filter2', function(){
  $sameObject = // I want to fetch sameObject;
  if(isset($sameObject){
    return Redirect::to('home')
  }
});
```

Is there any way to make DRY that's process?

Comment: `if(View::shared('obj'))` might do the trick, if you make sure the second filter runs later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using session, or config (gimmick) methods:

```
Route::filter('filter1', function(){
  $sameObject = // I want to fetch sameObject;
  Config::set('myObject',$sameObject);
  View::share('obj', $sameObject);
});

Route::filter('filter2', function(){
  $sameObject = Config::get('myObject');
  if(isset($sameObject){
    return Redirect::to('home')
  }
```

});